# Create Batch file to copy one folder and then generate it 1,000 times naming it 'AE 0001' up to 'AE 1000'

Tags: batch-file

I've had a look around, and I found some stuff that kinda worked, but I'm new to all this batch stuff.

I'm looking for a batch script that will copy one folder and everything in it. The folder is called

Package Master

I then want it to make 1,000 copies of that folder and rename each one sequentially:

AE 0001

to

AE 1000

If anyone is able to help, it'd be great if they could explain the process too so I can learn how it comes together and put myself in a stronger position for tweaking later.

Comment: What did you already try?  Did you use double % signs?

Comment: I found some code which was able to generate the folders in CMD but, uh, lost the code and I'm on a work system that's fairly locked down, so I can't even check history to find the page I got it from and I can't find it again. :(

Comment: Does this need to be a batch file specifically? It's probably much easier to accomplish in Powershell.

Comment: I'd say batch, just because I know I can use bat files - these systems are locked down really, really tightly and don't know what Powershell is or if it'd work on here. Can't install anything, limited rights to run things, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I copy a folder 1000 times naming it "AE 0001" up to "AE 1000"

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem loop 1000 times
for /l %%i in (1,1,1000) do (
  rem prefix the count with leading zeros
  set "_number=000%%i"
  rem recursively copy the directory and its contents
  rem target name is "AE " + 4 digit count with leading zeros
  xcopy "Package Master" "AE !_number:~-4!" /s /i
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Is there a way to set it to start from a specific number and pick up from there?

> So start at AE 0140 and climb from there for example?

Just change the `for /l` loop as follows:

```
for /l %%i in (140,1,1000) do (
```

---

#### Syntax

> ```
> FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> - start       : The first number
> - step        : The amount by which to increment the sequence
> - end         : The last number

Source - [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

Comment: I get a parse error?

Comment: Apologies, Was missing a `"` after `"Package Master` on the `xcopy`. Answer updated.

Comment: That's amazing - you've literally shaved hours off of my working day and let me focus on my real job!! Is there a way to set it to start from a specific number and pick up from there? So start at AE 0140 and climb from there for example?

Comment: Yes, of course. Answer updated. Please read the reference links.

Comment: You're a gent - thanks a ton. I think I've done the right thing to accept your answer?